# Render an excel sheet on Angular2 using ag grid

Tags: excel, angular, ag-grid

I have to render an excel sheet in ag grid on an angulart2 project. The data will be displayed in form of excel sheet where Columns will be maximum used columns in excel A, B, C...etc. and rows will be maximum used rows in excel 1,2,3..etc. Each cell in the sheet will have its own unique style and data. How can I render such grid in ag grid where I will set each cells styling separately without any performance lag?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example of excel sheet rendering using ag-grid and sheetJS which should give you all the options that you need:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/?framework=javascript#example-custom-xlsx&gsc.tab=0

Comment: Thanks, but above example is for rendering grid data into excel. However, I need logic to load excel sheet in ag-grid. This was achieved by passing worksheet column and row info as column and row definition to ag-grid and passing all the style info in row data so that it can be accessed in cell renderer for applying individual celll styling in ag-grid.

Comment: sample row data:       this.rowData = [
            {
                "0": {
                    "Text": "1",
                    "BackgroundColor": "",
                    "BackgroundColor2": "",
                    "BottomBorder": null,
                    "TopBorder": null,
                    "LeftBorder": null,
                    "RightBorder": null
                },

Comment: sample column def:  this.columnDefs.push({
                "Id": element.Id, headerName: element.headerName, "field": element.field, cellRenderer: function (params) {
                    console.log(params.value);
                    params.eGridCell.style.backgroundColor = params.value.BackgroundColor;
                    params.eGridCell.style.borderBottomWidth = params.value.BottomBorder;
                    return params.value.Text
                }